# How to use each replacement only once in a list of replacements

Tags: function-construction, replacement

I have a list of replacements and some list they are acting on. However, some RHS of the replacements rules are identical (the LHS is not). I want to use those rules one after another (perhaps cycling after they run out but the amount of replacements and occurrences match in the application I am looking at now).

So for example

```
replaceOnceOnly[{a, b, a}, {a -> 1, a -> 2, b -> 3}]
```

would output `{1,3,2}`. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

---

I should have included the following:
The replacement should act only on the whole of the list entry. I.e. the RHS is always an explicit element of the list the replacement acts on. It should not act on replaceOnceOnly[{f[a]},{a->1}] should not do anything. (Nor shall such an element even occur in the list to be acted on.) Also I want the replacements to act in a clear order: so from left to right for example.

(The other case is certainly interesting too but not what I am looking for.)

Comment: Do you want the replacements to apply only to the (whole) expression at level 1?  If not, is the order of application to be depth first? Perhaps your use-case is limited, but I'm wondering about `b^a + 2 a` versus `b^a + x a`, in which the orderless property sorts the power term into a different position. Also `{a b, b, a}`.

Comment: @MichaelE2, yes I would like it to apply only to the whole expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to use the following:

```
GeneralUtilities`ListIterator
GeneralUtilities`IteratorExhausted
```

Then it can be done with `Replace` or `ReplaceAll`:

```
Needs@"GeneralUtilities`"

Module[{hold},
  SetAttributes[hold, HoldAll];
  
  oneTimeRules[rules_] :=
   
   Normal@Merge[rules, ListIterator] /. Rule -> RuleDelayed /. 
     i_GeneralUtilities`Iterator :> 
      With[{r = Read[i]}, hold[r, r =!= IteratorExhausted]] /. 
    hold -> Condition;
  
  ];
```

Example:

```
Replace[{a, b, a, a, b, b}, oneTimeRules@{a -> 1, a -> 2, b -> 3}, 1]
```

> ```
> (*  {1, 3, 2, a, b, b}  *)
> ```

It does not work with patterns:

```
Replace[{a, b, a, a, b, b}, 
 oneTimeRules@{x_ -> f[x], x_ -> 2, b -> 3}, 1]
```

> ```
> (* {f[x], 2, a, a, 3, b}  <-- should be f[a] *)
> ```

---

**Addendum**

I thought this modification of @Nasser's approach (now deleted), derived from , seemed a better idea.  It seems to work with patterns.

```
ClearAll[useOnce, useRepeated];
SetAttributes[useRepeated, Listable];
useRepeated[(Rule | RuleDelayed)[pat_, repl_], n_ : 1] :=
  Module[{used = 0},
   pat :> repl /; used++ < n
   ];
useOnce[r_] := useRepeated[r];

Replace[{a, b, a, a, b, b}, useOnce@{a -> 1, a -> 2, b -> 3}, 1]
(*  {1, 3, 2, a, b, b}  *)

Replace[{a, b, a, a, b, b}, useOnce@{x_ -> f[x], x_ -> 2 x, b -> 3}, 1]
(*  {f[a], 2 b, a, a, 3, b}  *)
```

The function `useRepeated` lets a rule be applied up to `n` times, by default `1`. The function `useOnce` is shorthand `useRepeated` with `n = 1`. The `*Iterator` family uses similar internal data to keep track of where an `Iterator` is, so if I were using this, I'd prefer `useOnce`.

Comment: I'll probably delete it in a bit....since I got @Nasser's to work.

Comment: hi Michael. I am busy now, but I see you have a nice answer here. Mine above was just a sketch of possible method. I will delete my answer because not complete as you mentioned, it is no problem at all.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thank you, it seems to work excellently!

Answer (score 5):

This uses [`FirstPosition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FirstPosition.html) and [`ReplacePart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html). It works on the OP's example, not sure how extensible it is.

```
replaceOnceOnly[expr_, rules_] := Module[{val = expr, part},
    Function[
        If[Not[MissingQ[part = FirstPosition[val, #]]],
            val = ReplacePart[val, part -> #2]
        ]
    ]@@@rules;
    val
];
In[14]:= replaceOnceOnly[{a, b, a}, {a -> 1, a -> 2, b -> 3}]

Out[14]= {1, 3, 2}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here a solution which will adjust the behaviour of a set of rules which contains "duplicate" rules:

```
adjust[strategy_, rules_] :=
  Hold@@@GatherBy[rules, First] //
  Map[With[{vs = #[[All, 2]]}, strategy[RuleDelayed@@{#[[1, 1]], Unevaluated@vs}]]&]

cycle[k_ :> vs_] := Module[{i = 0}, k :> vs[[1+Mod[i++, Length@vs]]]]
oneshot[k_ :> vs_] := Module[{i = 0}, k :> Module[{ii = ++i}, vs[[ii]] /; ii <= Length[vs]]]
padlast[k_ :> vs_] := Module[{i = 0}, k :> vs[[Min[++i, Length[vs]]]]]
normal[k_ :> _[v_, ___]] := k :> v
```

**Multiple Strategies**

The various strategies are...

... `cycle` which cycles through the rules repeatedly:

```
{a, b, a, b, b, b, a, a} /. adjust[cycle, {a -> 1, a -> 2, b -> 3}]

(* {1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2} *)
```

... `padlast` which reuses the last rule as "padding":

```
{a, b, a, b, b, b, a, a} /. adjust[padlast, {a -> 1, a -> 2, b -> 3}]

(* {1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2} *)
```

... `oneshot` which just lets the rules run out:

```
{a, b, a, b, b, b, a, a} /. adjust[oneshot, {a -> 1, a -> 2, b -> 3}]

(* {1, 3, 2, b, b, b, a, a} *)
```

... and `normal` which is the regular behaviour where extra "duplicates" are ignored:

```
{a, b, a, b, b, b, a, a} /. adjust[normal, {a -> 1, a -> 2, b -> 3}]

(* {1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1} *)
```

***RuleDelayed* Replacements**

The solution also supports replacements that use `RuleDelayed` (`:>`).

Given:

```
$rules =
  { f[x_] :> x, f[x_] :> 10x, f[x_] :> 100x
  , g[x_] :> -x, g[x_] :> -10x
  , h[x_] :> Echo["Evaluation Leak!"]
  };

$exprs = {f[1], g[2], f[3], g[4], f[5], f[6], g[7]};
```

Then:

```
$exprs /. adjust[cycle, $rules]
(* {1,-2,30,-40,500,6,-7} *)

$exprs /. adjust[oneshot, $rules]
(* {1,-2,30,-40,500,f[6],g[7]} *)

$exprs /. adjust[padlast, $rules]
(* {1,-2,30,-40,500,600,-70} *)

$exprs /. adjust[normal, $rules]
(* {1,-2,3,-4,5,6,-7} *)
```

**Limited Support for *Condition***

Beware that the exhibited implementation only supports `Condition` (`/;`) on the left-hand side of a rule:

```
Range[10] /.
  adjust[cycle, {x_ /; x < 7 :> "small", x_ /; x < 7 :> "little"}]

(* {small,little,small,little,small,little,7,8,9,10} *)
```

It does not support conditions on the right-hand side, whether "bare" or nested within a scoping construct:

```
1 /. adjust[cycle, {x_ :> "small" /; x < 7}]

(* incorrect result:   small /; 1 < 7 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this does the trick. It's a bit ugly and procedural though:

```
useRulesOnce[item_, rules_] := Module[{result, citem = item, rrules},
  rrules = Reap[Do[
      With[{repl = (citem /. r)}, 
        If[repl =!= citem, citem = repl; 
         (* Print["replacing using " <> ToString[r]] *), Sow[r]]];
      , {r, rules}]] /. Null -> Nothing;
  Return[{citem, Flatten[rrules]}]]

replaceOnceList[list_, rules_] := 
 Module[{newItem, remainingRules = rules},
  Reap[Do[
     {newItem, remainingRules} = useRulesOnce[ item , remainingRules];
     Sow[newItem];
     , {item, list}]][[-1, 1]]
  ]

replaceOnceList[{a, b, a}, {a -> 1, a -> 2, b -> 3}]
(* result: {1,3,2} *)
```

This works with patterns too, and you can see which rules it chose if you enable the `Print` comment in `useRulesOnce`:

```
replaceOnceList[{Sin[4], Sin[5], a, Sin[3], b, a}, 
 {a -> 1, 
  Sin[x_ /; EvenQ[x]] :> 0,
  Sin[x_ /; OddQ[x]] :> -1,
  b -> 4,
  a -> 5}]

(* replacing using Sin[x_ /; EvenQ[x]] :> 0
   replacing using Sin[x_ /; OddQ[x]] :> -1
   replacing using a -> 1
   replacing using b -> 4
   replacing using a -> 5

   {0, -1, 1, Sin[3], 4, 5} *)
```