# Evaluating expressions by applying corresponding rules stored in another list

Tags: replacement, list-manipulation, rule

I have a list of expressions:

`{x,x^2,x^3}`

and a list of rules

`{x->1,x->2,x->3}`

How can I get `{1,4,27}` by applying the rule to the expression in the corresponding location?

Answer (score 18):

```
MapThread[ReplaceAll,{{x,x^2,x^3},{x->1,x->2,x->3}}]
```

Comment: `{{x, x^2, x^3}, {x -> 1, x -> 2, x -> 3}} // MapThread[ReplaceAll]`

Answer (score 11):

I would use `MapThread` as it is the function designed for this purpose; but here is another solution step by step:

```
flist = {x, x^2, x^3}
rules = {x -> 1, x -> 2, x -> 3}
Transpose@{flist, rules}
```

> ```
> {{x, x -> 1}, {x^2, x -> 2}, {x^3, x -> 3}}
> ```

Applying `ReplaceAll` to each sublist:

```
ReplaceAll @@@ Transpose@{flist, rules}
```

> {1, 4, 27}

---

Not immediately relevant, but you can try the following variations:

```
x^# /. x -> # & /@ Range[3]

#^# & /@ Range[3]

Array[#^# &, 3]

Table[i^i, {i, 3}]
```

Answer (score 9):

We define the following lists:

```
list = {x, x^2, x^3};
rules = {x -> 1, x -> 2, x -> 3};
```

And then we can run

> 0. [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html)

```
i[{ii_, iii_}] := ii /. iii;
```

- $\#_1$

The following:

```
Map[i, Transpose@{list, rules}]
```

and

- $\#_2$

equivalently

```
Map[i, Thread@{list, rules}]
```

> 1. [`Inner`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inner.html) + [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html)

```
Inner[ReplaceAll, list, rules, List]
```

> 2. Using [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html)

```
ReplaceAll @@@ Thread[{list, rules}]
```

> 3. Why not [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html)

```
Table[list[[i]] /. rules[[i]], {i, Length@rules}]
```

> 4. What on earth are these [`@#%^&*?!`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616)

```
fnctn = #1 /. #2 & @@@ Transpose@({##}) &;

fnctn[list, rules]
```

> 5. [`MapIndexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html) served well

```
MapIndexed[#^# &, Range@Length@list]
```

> 6. [`Last`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Last.html) + [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html)

```
Last /@ Power[List @@@ rules, Range[Length@rules]]
```

> 7. [`While`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/While.html) also works

```
Module[{return = {}, i = 1, end = Length@list},
 While[i <= end,
  AppendTo[return, list[[i]] /. rules[[i]]]; i++]; return]
```

> 8. Using [`For`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/For.html) because...why not?

```
Module[{return = {}}, For[
  i = 1, i <= Length@list, i++,
  AppendTo[return, list[[i]] /. rules[[i]]]];
 return]
```

> 9. After a lot of trial and error --- see again these weird [`@#%^&*?!`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616) stuff

```
smthng = {#1 /. #4, #2 /. #5, #3 /. #6} & @@ (## & @@@ {##}) &;
smthng[list, rules]
```

> 10. Something fancier using [`GeneralUtilities`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/225929/how-to-use-each-replacement-only-once-in-a-list-of-replacements/225937#225937)

Taking from the relevant code from said post, we have:

```
Needs@"GeneralUtilities`"
Module[{hold},
  SetAttributes[hold, HoldAll];
  
  oneTimeRules[rules_] :=
   
   Normal@Merge[rules, ListIterator] /. Rule -> RuleDelayed /. 
     i_GeneralUtilities`Iterator :> 
      With[{r = Read[i]}, hold[r, r =!= IteratorExhausted]] /. 
    hold -> Condition;
  
  ];
```

and then

```
Replace[list, oneTimeRules@rules, Length@rules]
```

> 11. Another fancy approach based on  [`Michael E2's answer`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/225929/how-to-use-each-replacement-only-once-in-a-list-of-replacements/225937#225937). This serves as a clarifying comment. Grab the relevant code that is needed

```
SetAttributes[useRepeated, Listable];
useRepeated[(Rule | RuleDelayed)[pat_, repl_], n_ : 1] :=
  Module[{used = 0},
   pat :> repl /; used++ < n
   ];
useOnce[r_] := useRepeated[r];
```

and then use

```
Replace[list, useOnce@rules, Length@rules]
```

or equivalently

```
ReplaceAll[list, useOnce@rules]
```

Note: if one uses `Replace` and the default value of the command -which is set to `1`- the above does not work. So some minor caution is needed.

> 12. Laborious stuff, but works

- $\#_1$

The following:

```
(Transpose[{list, Values@rules}] /. {x, i_} -> {i, i} /. {x^2, 
  i_} :> {i^2, i} /. {x^3, i_} :> {i^3, i})[[All, 1]]
```

and

- $\#_2$

equivalently

```
(Thread[{list, Values@rules}] /. {x, i_} -> {i, i} /. {x^2, 
  i_} :> {i^2, i} /. {x^3, i_} :> {i^3, i})[[All, 1]]
```

---

---

All of the above give

> [image: 1427]

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {x, x^2, x^3};

b = {x -> 1, x -> 2, x -> 3};
```

Two more possibilities:

```
Diagonal[a /. List /@ b]
```

> {1, 4, 27}

```
ReplacePart[a, i_ :> (a[[i]] /. b[[i]])]
```

> {1, 4, 27}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {x, x^2, x^3};

rules = {x -> 1, x -> 2, x -> 3};
```

---

Using `SubsetMap`:

```
SubsetMap[Diagonal@*Function[x, #] &@list, Values@#, Values@#] &@rules
```

> {1, 4, 27}

Or using `Outer`:

```
Diagonal@Outer[ReplaceAll, list, rules]
```

> {1, 4, 27}